# WPF Window resize "eats" controls width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an issue im struggling a day now. Im trying to center some controls into a Grid layout. I have 2 columns and i want half of the controls centered ad the 1st column and other half to the second column

When the window resize **some** of them get "eaten" on the edges , and i wasent able to identify the issue

[image]

Can anyone spot the issue?

```
  <Grid Margin="0,2,0,-2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


//....... 
 <ComboBox x:Name="optMenuLeft"  Margin="0,271,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="170" Grid.RowSpan="2"  />
 <Label Content="Menu" Margin="141,271,390,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="69" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
 <ComboBox x:Name="optBedOccupancyLeft"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="170" Margin="0,240,0,0"/>
 <Label Content="Bed Occupancy" Margin="0,240,270,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="94"/>
//.......
  <ComboBox Name="optMenuRight"  Margin="255,271,175,0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="170"/>
  <Label Content="Menu" Margin="176,271,353,0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="71"/>
  <ComboBox Name="optBedOccupancyRight"  Margin="255,240,175,0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="170" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
  <Label Content="Bed Occupancy" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,240,200,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="94"/>
//.....
```

Comment: It's the Margins which cut off the Labels and ComboBoxes.

Comment: @tobyUCT any idea how to solve this but still keep the controls at the desired locations?

Comment: You could play with the column widths and design the window like that. For instance three columns: Width "auto", Width "*" and Width "auto" again which would put the first column to the left, the third to the right and the 2nd one is filling the middle according to window size.

Comment: have you try using viewbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use grids inside grid. The outer grid will split the window into two columns. The inner grids will split the columns into four cells (2x2). Just center the inner grids and it will work like a charm.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="LeftColumn" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Bed Occupancy" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="optBedOccupancyLeft"  Grid.Column="1" />

        <Label Content="Menu" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <ComboBox  x:Name="optMenuLeft" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="RightColumn" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center>
        <!-- the same as left column -->
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Btw, notice, that when you want split some are to equal columns (or rows or both), you can use UniformGrid:

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Rows="1">
    <Grid x:Name="LeftColumn" />
    <Grid x:Name="RightColumn" />
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the 2 detailed answers , i started implementing this and i will accept it as an answer in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

There is also more advanced approach that I often use:

1. Use **UniformGrid** to define columns. The xaml is smaller and cleaner.
2. Use **HeaderedContentControl** to define labels and inputs
3. Use **Grid's SharedSizeScope** feature, to make width of label equal: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Rows="1">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LeftColumn" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Bed Occupancy" Style="{StaticResource LabelValueContentControl}">
            <ComboBox x:Name="optBedOccupancyLeft" />
        </HeaderedContentControl>

        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Menu" Style="{StaticResource LabelValueContentControl}" >
            <ComboBox x:Name="optMenuLeft" />
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="RightColumn"  Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <!-- the same as left column -->
    </StackPanel>

</UniformGrid>
```

The LabelCalueControlStyle is take advantage of shared column size

```
<Style x:Key="LabelValueContentControl" TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LabelValueContentControl.Label" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" 
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```